# ExtJs Object #<error> has no method 'indexOf'

Tags: extjs, extjs4, indexof, extjs-grid

I am trying to edit a number of cells in the grid. I am able to edit all cells except one cell. All cells have same data type i.e. string. When I click on that particular cell, I get the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<error> has no method 'indexOf'  in ext-all-dev.js
```

in the following block:

```
 urlAppend : function(url, string) {
            if (!Ext.isEmpty(string)) {
                return url + (url.indexOf('?') === -1 ? '?' : '&') + string;
        }
```

> During debugging, I can see that the value of 'url' in the code block
>   shown above is set to 'true'.

It is clear from this that 'true' does not have the method 'indexOf'.
But I am unable to understand why the URL is being set as true. The console errors do not point to any of the JS files created by me. How can I find what I am doing wrong?

Comment: CAn you post your model and the column renderer.

Comment: How can we find this out with just this tiny bit of code? You could also ask it like this: **My method is called with a wrong argument type. Here is the code of the called method please tell me why this happens**

Comment: @Darin Kolev: Hi Darin, thanks for your response. Actually, I had one option autoLoad:true which was causing the problem. As soon as I turned it off, it started displaying the dropdown.

Comment: @seba: seba, you are right. I should have posted something more. But I was so much confused myself, that I couldn't understand what to post. Moreover, all console errors only pointed to the ext-all-dev.js file. You can see that particular method in the question. The problem has been solved now. It was created by autoLoad:true in the editor for xtype:combo. Thank you for trying to help me out.